# MacBook Air doesn't detect built in display

Tags: display, sleep-wake, monterey

I recently updated to **MacOS 12.5 (21G72)** and now my 2018 MacBook Air no longer detects the built in Retina display when waking up from sleep while connected to my external monitor. The built in display remains blank and the external monitor is the primary display.

I have tried the following:

1. Unplugging the cable to the monitor, but the built in monitor remains blank.
2. Adding another Display (my iPad) from System Preferences > Displays and pressing Option does give me access to the Detect Displays button. But clicking on that button does not result in the system detecting the built in display.

Currently, the only method for restoring use of the built in display is to perform a hardware reset on the system. Whether or not the MacBook is attached to the external monitor, the system restarts with a usable built in display. (A software Restart from the Apple menu only brings the system back with the same issue.) What will remedy this lack of display detection after sleep? What has changed in this update of MacOS Monterey?